# How do I change the verification method when using the Google .net client library for Webmaster Tools?

Tags: .net, gdata-api, google-search-console

```
var settings = new RequestSettings("appname", "googleusername", "googlepassword");
var service = new WebmasterToolsRequest(settings);
var site = new Sites("http://www.mysite.com", "text/plain");
Sites resultSite = service.AddSite(site);
resultSite.VerificationMethod.Type = "htmlpage";
resultSite.SitesEntry.Update();
```

.Update fails with a 400 (Bad Request).

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

ps.  It almost seems easier to just code to the raw google api, this particular library seems to be like vb6, easy to do the easy things, hard to impossible to the do the medium to hard things...

Comment: I know that additional xml nodes are added to the .ExtensionElements list, and that both of the VerificationMethods are present in the returned xml feed.

I thought of doing a lookup of the htmlpage node in the ExtensionElements and replacing the current contents of VerificationMethod, but I don't know how to convert the xmlnode to whatever type VerificationMethod represents.

And that still doesn't tell me how to update the resulting feed.

Comment: I tried contacting Google, but they were not impressed with my request to reboot their server cluster, so, no. ;)